# VelocityEngine not parsing template [in struts]

Tags: java, tomcat, struts, velocity, templating

So I'm just getting started with Velocity and trying to figure it out with a small and simple experiment. Now directly loading the template from the file proved something of a bust so I fetched it via a StringResourceLoader instead.

```
servletContext = ServletActionContext.getServletContext();

//Set up Velocity
VelocityEngine ve = new VelocityEngine();
ve.setProperty ("runtime.log.logsystem.class", "org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.NullLogSystem");
ve.setProperty ("resource.loader", "string");
ve.setProperty ("string.resource.loader.class", "org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.StringResourceLoader");
ve.init();

//get a template
StringResourceRepository repo = StringResourceLoader.getRepository();
String templateName = "documentReminder";
String templateContent = getTemplateContent(); //fetches a string from a file
repo.putStringResource(templateName, templateContent); //the resource.loader = string makes this work
Template template = ve.getTemplate(templateName);

//add data to context
VelocityContext vContext = new VelocityContext();
vContext.put("name", "Bob");

//render template into a Stringwriter and spit it out to screen
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
template.merge(vContext, writer);
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
out.print(writer.toString());
```

The template is nice and simple:

```
<h1>Hi $name</h1>
```

I dug out the following from logs:

```
DEBUG velocity:155 - Null reference [template 'documentReminder', line 9, column 16] : $name cannot be resolved.
```

Now this will happily fetch the template, but spits it out unchanged, without inserting the name. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: You're aware that S2 has Velocity responses out-of-the-box, I assume?

Answer (score 0):

Ended up going down a slightly different route to solving this problem.

```
public class TemplateParser {

    public static final TemplateParser INSTANCE = new TemplateParser();
    private static final String TEMPLATE_PATH_BASE = "WEB-INF/velocitytemplates/";
    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass());

    public static final String TEMPLATE_DOCUMENT_REMINDER = "document_reminder";

    private HashMap<String, String> templates = new HashMap<String, String>(); //will be lazy-loading these
    private static final Map<String, String> templatePaths; //populate in the {static} and make unmodifiable
    static{
        HashMap<String, String> pathsTemp = new HashMap<String, String>();
        pathsTemp.put(TEMPLATE_DOCUMENT_REMINDER, "documentReminder.html.vm");
        templatePaths = Collections.unmodifiableMap(pathsTemp);
    }

    /**
     * Set up the template parser. Singleton model. Velocity properties are set here.
     */
    protected TemplateParser(){
        //set up log4j - if we don't set up logging it crashes with a nullpointerexception
        Velocity.setProperty ("runtime.log.logsystem.class", "org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.SimpleLog4JLogSystem");
        Velocity.setProperty ("runtime.log.logsystem.log4j.category", "velocity");
        Velocity.setProperty ("runtime.log.logsystem.log4j.logger", "velocity");
        try {
            Velocity.init();
        } catch (Exception e){
            logger.debug ("Problems initialising velocity for com.etime.util.TemplateParser");
        }
        logger.debug("com.etime.util.MailTemplateParser initialised");
    }

    /**
     * Get the active instance of this object as per singleton model
     * @return TemplateParser
     */
    public static TemplateParser getInstance(){
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    /**
     * Parse a template. Pass a VelocityContext and template name (all listed as static strings).
     * @param context Create and pass a new VelocityContext - essentially a map <String, Object>
     * @param template Find template names in the static strings for the TemplateParser class
     * @return A parsed template as a string to do with as you see fit
     */
    public String parse(VelocityContext context, String template){
        String templateContent = getTemplateContent(template);

        //Parse the template and handle errors where present
        StringWriter w = new StringWriter();
        try {
            Velocity.evaluate(context, w, "TemplateParserLog", templateContent); //the lazy way, but it works
        } catch (ParseErrorException e) {
            logger.debug("ParseError " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MethodInvocationException e) {
            logger.debug("MethodInvocationException " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.debug("Unknown Exception " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return w.toString();
    }//parse

    /**
     * Fetch the template content, either from the cached copy (templates) or direct through the file.
     * @param template
     * @return
     */
    private String getTemplateContent(String template) {
        ServletContext servletContext = ServletActionContext.getServletContext(); //get this so paths don't suck
        String content = templates.get(template); //fetch pre-fetched template if existent
        if (content == null){ //not already got content, let's load it lazily
            String templatePath = templatePaths.get(template);
            if (templatePath != null){
                BufferedReader br = null;
                try {
                    String fullTemplatePath = servletContext.getRealPath(TEMPLATE_PATH_BASE+templatePath); //get a proper path
                    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fullTemplatePath)); //read file to a BufferedReader

                    //Push out bufferedReader to a string [content]
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    String line = br.readLine();

                    while (line != null) {
                        sb.append(line);
                        sb.append("\n");
                        line = br.readLine();
                    }
                    content = sb.toString();
                    br.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }//template path exists
        }//not already got content, let's load it lazily

        return content;
    }//getTemplateContent

}//class
```

One can then create a VelocityContext, add content to it (a lot like an android bundle tbh) and pass in the VelocityContent.TEMPLATE_DOCUMENT_REMINDER or another template name to the parse function to do the job. This is working. It seems that relying on the resourceloader is probably dodgy, handling that myself and passing the actual strings and letting Velocity take it from there has proven more effective, and is reasonably elegant in this case, with no major performance hit that I can see.

Comment: The resource loader works fine. My original content still stands: why on earth would you duplicate functionality already provided by the framework? You've duplicated so much existing functionality here I barely know how to respond.